# Matrix related question, need help in understanding one conceptual thing

Tags: matrices

I have been preparing for an examination and faced one question. 
[image]

This is from Korean Scholastic Assessment Test

Translation is "The following graph shows the relationship between each vertex
The number of elements in the matrix is" from google.
Can someone help me to understand what this thing is and what kind of approach is needed to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned how to solve this types of questions [This link helped me](http://www.math.unm.edu/~loring/links/graph_s09/degreeSeq.pdf)

Here we need to consider each point and how many line connections each pint has and form a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 &4 & 2&2&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Here google translate performed a little mistake the question is asking for the sum of all elements of the matrix

I have checked the answer it is 14